# Spark DataFrame saveAsTable with partitionBy creates no ORC file in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe which I want to save as Hive table with partitions. I tried the following two statements but they don't work. I don't see any ORC files in HDFS directory, it's empty. I can see baseTable is there in Hive console but obviously it's empty because of no files inside HDFS.

The following two lines `saveAsTable()` and `insertInto()`do not work. registerDataFrameAsTable() method works but it creates in memory table and causing OOM in my use case as I have thousands of Hive partitions to process. I am new to Spark.

```
dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("entity","date").format("orc").saveAsTable("baseTable"); 

dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("orc").partitionBy("entity","date").insertInto("baseTable");

//the following works but creates in memory table and seems to be reason for OOM in my case
    
hiveContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(dataFrame, "baseTable");
```

Comment: Use this `dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("entity","date").format("orc").save("baseTable");` and try to put the full path in `save()`, not the relative one.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have already got your answer , but posting this answer for others reference, partitionBy was only supported for Parquet till Spark 1.4 , support for ORC ,JSON, text and avro was added in version 1.5+ please refer the doc below

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html